# How rabbitmq know consumer to service or pod binding where its present

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Let say I have two pods (running same service) and pod1 own queue (1 to 5) and pod2 own queue (6 to 10); so question is how RabbitMQ know which message need to process by pod1 or pod2? I mean how or where consumer to pod binding is present?
how message is delivered to pod1 and not to pod2?

curious to know the flow

Answer (score 0):

The message is delivered from queue to the consumer subscribed to it.
If you have several consumers to the same queue, then it is called concurrent subscription and messages from the same queue are delivered in round-robin manner according to prefetch configuration.

If you second pod is not subscribed to queues 1 to 5, then messages from them will never be delivered to that second pod.